# Using Google sign-In for website, is there a way to programmatically sign in?

Tags: google-cloud-endpoints, google-authentication, google-oauth, google-signin

.. or to sign in without rendering the button?

The Google docs shown [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/build-button) outlines how to create a Google sign in button. Upon rendering the button, if the user has already signed in, I am guessing that means a valid token is available, the sign in button switches its text to "Signed In" and the onSuccess callback is called.

This looks a bit sloppy so I was wondering if there was a way to programmatically sign in and only render the button when the user is not already signed in.

My end goal is to call my Google Cloud Endpoints backend methods with authentication.

Answer (score 2):

Ultimately the Sign-In button is just a DOM element with some handlers on it which hook into the Google auth infrastructure. You can trigger a sign-in using `GoogleAuth.signIn` and pass the "prompt" parameter to hide the prompt to the user. If their browser already has a valid token in cookies, it'll sign-in and you can hide the button as part of your sign-in callback.

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference

Comment: If they are not signed in it just waits and the promise does nothing. How do you check if they are signed in programmatically?

Comment: I am using signIn() with `prompt: 'none'`, but it does not appear to be working as documented. First there is still a modal window appearing for a quick second till it dismisses itself, secondly if the user is not logged in no error is returned, neither promise functions are responding. Is this a bug?

Comment: So apparently the promise is only fulfilled upon successful login. So you have to run isSignedIn() after attempting signIn({prompt: 'none'}). Still doesn't address the modal window that is appearing for a second. Should I report this as a bug?

Comment: Wait that doesn't work cause signIn() is asyc so you would have no way of knowing how long to wait before running isSignedIn()

Comment: What it seems like is there is no way around initially showing the button. You can hide it onSuccess, but there is no callback to tell you that we tried to auto sign In but failed. Seems rather poorly designed.

Comment: You have no need to show the button at any time, since as I said, it's a DOM element. DOM elements can have styling attached to them, including "display: none". Furthermore, interacting with javascript shouldn't be a problem - if a function is async, then the place to put logic which should run after it completes would be in the callback argument provided. I can't see any reason why an automatic attempt at login shouldn't be possible, with showing the button on failure, using the callback from `signIn({prompt: 'none'})`

Comment: The simple answer is because the failure callback is not called just because the user was not already authenticated and signing in without user interaction failed. This is true whether we are talking about the promise's fail callback when using signIn() or the onfailure option when using gapi.signin2.render(). A failed automatic sign in attempt will not call either of these failure callbacks. It will not call any callback. Yes, you could make the btn have `display:none`, but you would have no way of knowing if automatic sign in failed so you could set `display:block`.

Comment: I am not sure if this is a bug, but it is the case as of now.

Comment: The reason that plunkr doesn't work is because the client ID needs to be valid for the domain/route from which the auth is originating. If you got that client ID from a Cloud [Developers Console](https://console.developers.google.com) project, you should deploy the code to a project, not just a plunkr, where it won't work. When your code is used in the proper way, it doesn't throw any error as just tested from my end.

Comment: That ID was created for the Plunker specifically, with the Pluinker address as the origin. It works perfectly as you can see if you experiment with toggling the prompt option from "none" to "select_account". The problem is that the failure callback is not built to report failed automatic sign in attempts.

Comment: The function `GoogleAuth.signIn()` is described as returning: `A Promise that is fulfilled when the user successfully authenticates and grants the requested scopes.` It seems you're using the callback pattern for [`GoogleAuth.then()`](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference#googleauththenwzxhzdk60oninitwzxhzdk61_wzxhzdk62onfailurewzxhzdk63) on the promise returned from `GoogleAuth.signIn()`, which does take the two parameters.

Comment: I am a bit confused? `GoogleAuth.then()` is for initializing `auth2`. This should be successful either way, and has little to do with the sign in function. As far as I understand, all promises have three arguments: success, failure, and context. Either way, neither of them is being called. You pointed out that the documentation states that a callback is only triggered upon successful authentications, and there lies the problem. This is not in alignment with the OpenID Connect Request Parameters that the documentation claims to be bound to regarding the prompt parameter.

Comment: Therefore, there is no way to check if the user is already authenticated programmatically.